# How to Extract Hostname from Ansible Playbook Run

Tags: command-line, networking, scripts, automation

I need to accomplish following shell script. 
I trying to extract the HOSTNAME after it runs Successful via Ansible Playbook Run.

I have text file which contains Ansible-Playbook run command to be executed and writing the output into the log file: result.log

Here is what's the "result.log" file looks like

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
TESTLINUX01                : ok=6   changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

If the failed is "0", Unreachable is "0" and Changed is more then 0, then print the HOSTNAME only. In this case, TESTLINUX01

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's not really enough information in your question, but I'd guess something like `awk '/failed=0/ && /unreachable=0/ && !/changed=0/ {print $1}' result.log` would do it

Comment: thanks, I just tried and getting no results. Here is the entired log file

Comment: Ask about Mac OSX on [unix.se] or Ask Different - many command line utilities are not the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use someting like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="result.log"

changed=`grep -Po "changed=\K\d+" $file`
unreachable=`grep -Po "unreachable=\K\d+" $file`
failed=`grep -Po "failed=\K\d+" $file`

if [ $changed -ge 1 -a $unreachable -eq 0 -a $failed -eq 0 ]
 then
  cut -s -f1 -d: $file | tr -s ' '
fi
```

---

First we extract all necessary values then we compare them with your desired ones, if they where match we print out the host name.

- `grep -Po "changed=\K\d+` returns the number in front of "changed"
- IF statement:

  - `$changed -ge 1` if changed is greater that equal "1"
  - `-a` and
  - `$unreachable -eq 0` unreachable was equal to "0"
  - `-a` and
  - `$failed -eq 0` failed was equal to "0", Then:
- `cut -s -f1 -d: $file | tr -s ' '` prints the hostname

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept the answer if you think it was helpful to you ;)

Comment: Hello Ravexina, I'm working on MAC and the grep -Po doesn't work.
I tried using: 'grep -Eoi "changed=\d+"' $LOGFILE '| grep "[0-9]"' 
I get an empty result. Is there any way to only get the digit from the "changed"

Comment: These only work on `-P`, you can use sed instead `grep failed result.log | sed -r "s/.*changed=([0-9]*).*/\1/"`

Comment: grep failed result.log | sed "s/.*changed=([0-9]*)*.\/1/"
```sed: 1: "s/.*changed=([0-9]*)*.\/1/": unterminated substitute in regular expression```

Comment: I sugesst `sed -r` not `sed` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for replying and providing the solution. Following code works out for me:

```
cat $file
$file >> $LOGFILE

SUCCESS=`grep "unreachable=0    failed=0" $LOGFILE | awk '{printf "%s ", $1;}'`
echo "Success: $SUCCESS"

FAILURE=`grep -E "unreachable=0    failed=[1-9]" $LOGFILE | awk '{printf "%s ", $1;}'`
echo "Failure: $FAILURE"

Unreachable=`grep -E "unreachable=1    failed=0" $LOGFILE | awk '{printf "%s ", $1;}'`
echo "Unreachable: $Unreachable"
```